# Differentiate FK constraint exceptions from other db exceptions in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.1

I have an API (`.NET Core Web API`) with a lot of `POST` methods that need Foreign Keys IDs in data payload. If such FK doesn't exists in the database I want to throw BadRequest 400 status, if something else didn't work on the database side I want to throw 500 status. **How to differentiate FK constraint exceptions from other db exceptions?**

There is one catch to this question. As I'm using `EF Core` I wouldn't want to rely on particular DB provider (in production I use `Postgresql` and for my integration tests I'm using `In-Memory SQLite`).

**Here's my solution**, but I'm not sure if it's perfect:
If the method's data payload expects FK constraint IDs, before updating the database I basically check if such entity exists in the database. If not, I throw custom Exception, which I catch in middleware and thus the API response is always the same if the FK Id is invalid.

As you probably see, it's a little pessimistic approach. I'm wondering if there is an optimistic approach, so trust DB, let it fail in the DB, but when it fails, differentiate errors made by the client of the API (like wrong IDs) and return 400 instead of 500.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify. I'm not talking about wrong FK ids in the URL. I was talking about `POST` methods, so for example this request:

> URL: `/api/items`
>
> Data (json):
>
> ```
> {
>     "itemName": "Foo",
>     "addressId": 999999 <--- doesn't exists
> }
> ```

Right now, I'm checking if Address 999999 exists, before I add item. I'm not sure if this is a good practice. I was curious if I can let database fail and catch "wrong FK id" exception in the middleware. But the problem is, different SQL database engine throw different exceptions. So it's a problem for me as I have integration tests using `SQLite inMemory` and production using `Postgresql`.

Comment: I'm sure EF Core informs you of the nature of the exception (such as in your case, FK violations) as inner exceptions whenever a db operation fails?

Comment: You may not get all the request.  The request have to go through the server firewall so bad URLs or TLS not authenticated may not reach your service.  You are also going to get cases where the connection to the database fails and you have to handle those failures.  The database will only fail if the query (command text) is bad.

Comment: @jdweng please look at my EDIT. I'm not talking about URLs with wrong FKs. URL is perfectly fine, it's about data send in the request.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing extra checks especially if the checks are going to improve performance.  If you left out the ID the database would check every row of the database which may take minutes.  Your check for id would fail quickly which would save a lot of time.